# Database relationships design JPA

Tags: database, jpa, relationship

I have been wondering about how to design the relationships between entities in my app, I am kinda new to this. Can you help?

**WHAT APP? - CONTEXT**

I am trying to develop an app to help people track their expenses, calculate statistics etc., as a hobby project to train my poor skills in full-stack development.  The idea is that a user logs in and can add an expense, for example a chicken bought for 3 $ and the app will calculate his expense stats based on repeated input.

**WHAT DO I NEED TO FIND OUT?**

I have done users registration and logging in and am now creating the "SingleExpense" entity class. I am wondering how should the relationship between the expense and the user look like in this particular use case.

- Should the user have a Set of expenses as a field with @OneToMany annotation? But then whenever I fetch the user I will get all his expenses since forever, right? I might do the FetchType lazy or something, but I am looking for the cleanest, correct solution.
- Should the Expense have the User as  a field with @ManyToOne annotation? But then if I try to fetch all the expenses, the User objects will be fetched along right? And if I want to persist a new Expense I need to put the whole User object into the expense, yeah?
- Or maybe it should be bidirectional for some reason?

I am very confused with that, I hope you guys can try and explain to me what works and what doesn't and why. Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reason you explained, you should probably not have a OneToMany, since It would probably never be a good idea to ever load all the expenses of a given user. And even if some use case needs to do that, a simple JPQL query can do that.

So that leaves the second option, which is the right one. A ManyToOne can be lazy, too. So fetching an expense won't fetch the user unless you start using the value returned by `expense.getUser()`. And regarding the storage of a new expense:

- loading the user from the database, using `EntityManager.find()`, to store it in the new expense wouldn't be a big deal: loading an entity by its ID is extremely fast
- but even then, you don't actually need to load the user from the database if you assume it exists: you just need to get a lazy reference to the user, which you can obtain thanks to `EntityManager.getReference()`

Comment: thanks! that's what I did!